# Problems with Eclipse and Google Drive

Tags: eclipse, cloud, google-drive-api

Today I tried to switch my development environment from Dropbox to Google Drive. My complete development folder (30,000 files) is stored locally and synced to the cloud. Dropbox was working perfect for nearly a year but Google Drive is much cheaper currently - so I tried to do the same with Google Drive.

Google Drive shows upload errors for exactly one kind of directory. All of these directories are releated to eclipse.

The files in question are for example:

```
workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\<aproject>\
workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\<anotherproject>\
```

I did look at the attributes but I can't find anything special with these directories. Eclipse is not running.

What can I do?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've also come across problems using Google Driving as a Workspace in Eclipse. For the moment, I've fallen back to SpiderOak as my syncing platform..a shame.

Comment: After one day of testing I have to say that Google Drive trashed my environment. Two Windows 7 PCs (30.000 files in a huge workspace), the first machine did upload everything. After that I installed Google Drive on second machine and let this machine do sync down. This morning I did check sync sttus of source and target machine and everything on target machine was garbaged. Google Drive says Sync completed on both machines but wrong files did contain wrong content. Seems that Google Drive did mix the names. Never seen that before in several years with Dropbox. Currently I do a second test ...

Comment: If that fails too - I won't trust Google Drive. Yes, you are right. It's a shame. Today most of the time Google Drive says "Can't connect" or "Can't sync". Everything else is working on both machines BUT Google Drive.

Answer (score 3):

i found a forum it talk about this problem. they think Google fix the problem with eclipse in a few weeks... you can visit this link in http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/8DNEH3U6vbE

Comment: Thanks for your hint. In fact I Pause Google Drive before I start Eclipse and Resume afterwards. This works. But whenever I start Eclipse without Pausing Google Drive I'm in serious trouble always (duplicate files, etc. etc.).